# add js particule in header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to add the particle effect in javascript, on a project but I don't really know javascript

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Леда</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="logo">ADVENTURE</a>
      <div class="nav-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Infos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <img src="menu-btn.png" alt="menu navbar" class="menu-navbar">
    </nav>
    <div id="particle-canvas"></div>
  </header>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

header {
    background-image: url('landscape.jpg');
}

header {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-size: cover;
}

.navbar {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar a {
    color: white;
}

.navbar .nav-links ul {
    display: flex;
}

.navbar .nav-links ul li {
    margin: 0 25px;
}

.navbar .nav-links ul li.active a {
    margin: 0 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar .menu-navbar{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 35px;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .navbar {
        padding: 0;
    }

    .navbar .logo {
        position: absolute;
        top: 37px;
        left: 50px;
    }

    .navbar .menu-navbar {
        display: block;
        top: 30px;
        right: 50px;
    }

    .nav-links {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.233);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: -100%;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    .nav-links.mobile-menu {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .nav-links ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .navbar .nav-links ul li {
        margin: 25px 0;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}

#particle-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

js

```
const menuHamburger = document.querySelector(".menu-navbar")
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links")

menuHamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navLinks.classList.toggle('mobile-menu')
});


!function (a) { var b = "object" == typeof self && self.self === self && self || "object" == typeof global && global.global === global && global; "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["exports"], function (c) { b.ParticleNetwork = a(b, c) }) : "object" == typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = a(b, {}) : b.ParticleNetwork = a(b, {}) }(function (a, b) { var c = function (a) { this.canvas = a.canvas, this.g = a.g, this.particleColor = a.options.particleColor, this.x = Math.random() * this.canvas.width, this.y = Math.random() * this.canvas.height, this.velocity = { x: (Math.random() - .5) * a.options.velocity, y: (Math.random() - .5) * a.options.velocity } }; return c.prototype.update = function () { (this.x > this.canvas.width + 20 || this.x < -20) && (this.velocity.x = -this.velocity.x), (this.y > this.canvas.height + 20 || this.y < -20) && (this.velocity.y = -this.velocity.y), this.x += this.velocity.x, this.y += this.velocity.y }, c.prototype.h = function () { this.g.beginPath(), this.g.fillStyle = this.particleColor, this.g.globalAlpha = .7, this.g.arc(this.x, this.y, 1.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI), this.g.fill() }, b = function (a, b) { this.i = a, this.i.size = { width: this.i.offsetWidth, height: this.i.offsetHeight }, b = void 0 !== b ? b : {}, this.options = { particleColor: void 0 !== b.particleColor ? b.particleColor : "#fff", background: void 0 !== b.background ? b.background : "#1a252f", interactive: void 0 !== b.interactive ? b.interactive : !0, velocity: this.setVelocity(b.speed), density: this.j(b.density) }, this.init() }, b.prototype.init = function () { if (this.k = document.createElement("div"), this.i.appendChild(this.k), this.l(this.k, { position: "absolute", top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, "z-index": 1 }), /(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(this.options.background)) this.l(this.k, { background: this.options.background }); else { if (!/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i.test(this.options.background)) return console.error("Please specify a valid background image or hexadecimal color"), !1; this.l(this.k, { background: 'url("' + this.options.background + '") no-repeat center', "background-size": "cover" }) } if (!/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(this.options.particleColor)) return console.error("Please specify a valid particleColor hexadecimal color"), !1; this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"), this.i.appendChild(this.canvas), this.g = this.canvas.getContext("2d"), this.canvas.width = this.i.size.width, this.canvas.height = this.i.size.height, this.l(this.i, { position: "relative" }), this.l(this.canvas, { "z-index": "20", position: "relative" }), window.addEventListener("resize", function () { return this.i.offsetWidth === this.i.size.width && this.i.offsetHeight === this.i.size.height ? !1 : (this.canvas.width = this.i.size.width = this.i.offsetWidth, this.canvas.height = this.i.size.height = this.i.offsetHeight, clearTimeout(this.m), void (this.m = setTimeout(function () { this.o = []; for (var a = 0; a < this.canvas.width * this.canvas.height / this.options.density; a++)this.o.push(new c(this)); this.options.interactive && this.o.push(this.p), requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this)) }.bind(this), 500))) }.bind(this)), this.o = []; for (var a = 0; a < this.canvas.width * this.canvas.height / this.options.density; a++)this.o.push(new c(this)); this.options.interactive && (this.p = new c(this), this.p.velocity = { x: 0, y: 0 }, this.o.push(this.p), this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (a) { this.p.x = a.clientX - this.canvas.offsetLeft, this.p.y = a.clientY - this.canvas.offsetTop }.bind(this)), this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (a) { this.p.velocity = { x: (Math.random() - .5) * this.options.velocity, y: (Math.random() - .5) * this.options.velocity }, this.p = new c(this), this.p.velocity = { x: 0, y: 0 }, this.o.push(this.p) }.bind(this))), requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this)) }, b.prototype.update = function () { this.g.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height), this.g.globalAlpha = 1; for (var a = 0; a < this.o.length; a++) { this.o[a].update(), this.o[a].h(); for (var b = this.o.length - 1; b > a; b--) { var c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.o[a].x - this.o[b].x, 2) + Math.pow(this.o[a].y - this.o[b].y, 2)); c > 120 || (this.g.beginPath(), this.g.strokeStyle = this.options.particleColor, this.g.globalAlpha = (120 - c) / 120, this.g.lineWidth = .7, this.g.moveTo(this.o[a].x, this.o[a].y), this.g.lineTo(this.o[b].x, this.o[b].y), this.g.stroke()) } } 0 !== this.options.velocity && requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this)) }, b.prototype.setVelocity = function (a) { return "fast" === a ? 1 : "slow" === a ? .33 : "none" === a ? 0 : .66 }, b.prototype.j = function (a) { return "high" === a ? 5e3 : "low" === a ? 2e4 : isNaN(parseInt(a, 10)) ? 1e4 : a }, b.prototype.l = function (a, b) { for (var c in b) a.style[c] = b[c] }, b });

// Initialisation

var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('particle-canvas');
var options = {
    particleColor: '#888',
    interactive: true,
    speed: 'medium',
    density: 'high'
};
var particleCanvas = new ParticleNetwork(canvasDiv, options);
```

I copied and pasted the entire code but it gave me a problem. It covered my image and the navbar in blue and I can't see anything except a blue page with the particles. What needs to change in the code so that we see the image and the navbar and that the click on the navbar works.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be working OK except your canvas with the particles on it is 'on top' of the other stuff.

If you make the canvas go back (in the z axis sense - that is the axis that is orthogonal to the screen) then the header is seen.

Make canvas have z-index: -1;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Леда</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="logo">ADVENTURE</a>
      <div class="nav-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Infos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <img src="menu-btn.png" alt="menu navbar" class="menu-navbar">
    </nav>
    <div id="particle-canvas"></div>
  </header>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    header {
      background-image: url('landscape.jpg');
    }
    
    header {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 30px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .navbar .nav-links ul {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .navbar .nav-links ul li {
      margin: 0 25px;
    }
    
    .navbar .nav-links ul li.active a {
      margin: 0 25px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    
    .navbar .menu-navbar {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      width: 35px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
      .navbar {
        padding: 0;
      }
      .navbar .logo {
        position: absolute;
        top: 37px;
        left: 50px;
      }
      .navbar .menu-navbar {
        display: block;
        top: 30px;
        right: 50px;
      }
      .nav-links {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.233);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: -100%;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
      }
      .nav-links.mobile-menu {
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      .nav-links ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .navbar .nav-links ul li {
        margin: 25px 0;
        font-size: 2em;
      }
    }
    
    #particle-canvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    const menuHamburger = document.querySelector(".menu-navbar")
    const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links")

    menuHamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
      navLinks.classList.toggle('mobile-menu')
    });


    ! function(a) {
      var b = "object" == typeof self && self.self === self && self || "object" == typeof global && global.global === global && global;
      "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["exports"], function(c) {
        b.ParticleNetwork = a(b, c)
      }) : "object" == typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = a(b, {}) : b.ParticleNetwork = a(b, {})
    }(function(a, b) {
      var c = function(a) {
        this.canvas = a.canvas, this.g = a.g, this.particleColor = a.options.particleColor, this.x = Math.random() * this.canvas.width, this.y = Math.random() * this.canvas.height, this.velocity = {
          x: (Math.random() - .5) * a.options.velocity,
          y: (Math.random() - .5) * a.options.velocity
        }
      };
      return c.prototype.update = function() {
        (this.x > this.canvas.width + 20 || this.x < -20) && (this.velocity.x = -this.velocity.x), (this.y > this.canvas.height + 20 || this.y < -20) && (this.velocity.y = -this.velocity.y), this.x += this.velocity.x, this.y += this.velocity.y
      }, c.prototype.h = function() {
        this.g.beginPath(), this.g.fillStyle = this.particleColor, this.g.globalAlpha = .7, this.g.arc(this.x, this.y, 1.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI), this.g.fill()
      }, b = function(a, b) {
        this.i = a, this.i.size = {
          width: this.i.offsetWidth,
          height: this.i.offsetHeight
        }, b = void 0 !== b ? b : {}, this.options = {
          particleColor: void 0 !== b.particleColor ? b.particleColor : "#fff",
          background: void 0 !== b.background ? b.background : "#1a252f",
          interactive: void 0 !== b.interactive ? b.interactive : !0,
          velocity: this.setVelocity(b.speed),
          density: this.j(b.density)
        }, this.init()
      }, b.prototype.init = function() {
        if (this.k = document.createElement("div"), this.i.appendChild(this.k), this.l(this.k, {
            position: "absolute",
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            "z-index": 1
          }), /(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(this.options.background)) this.l(this.k, {
          background: this.options.background
        });
        else {
          if (!/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i.test(this.options.background)) return console.error("Please specify a valid background image or hexadecimal color"), !1;
          this.l(this.k, {
            background: 'url("' + this.options.background + '") no-repeat center',
            "background-size": "cover"
          })
        }
        if (!/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(this.options.particleColor)) return console.error("Please specify a valid particleColor hexadecimal color"), !1;
        this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"), this.i.appendChild(this.canvas), this.g = this.canvas.getContext("2d"), this.canvas.width = this.i.size.width, this.canvas.height = this.i.size.height, this.l(this.i, {
          position: "relative"
        }), this.l(this.canvas, {
          "z-index": "20",
          position: "relative"
        }), window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
          return this.i.offsetWidth === this.i.size.width && this.i.offsetHeight === this.i.size.height ? !1 : (this.canvas.width = this.i.size.width = this.i.offsetWidth, this.canvas.height = this.i.size.height = this.i.offsetHeight, clearTimeout(this.m), void(this.m = setTimeout(function() {
            this.o = [];
            for (var a = 0; a < this.canvas.width * this.canvas.height / this.options.density; a++) this.o.push(new c(this));
            this.options.interactive && this.o.push(this.p), requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this))
          }.bind(this), 500)))
        }.bind(this)), this.o = [];
        for (var a = 0; a < this.canvas.width * this.canvas.height / this.options.density; a++) this.o.push(new c(this));
        this.options.interactive && (this.p = new c(this), this.p.velocity = {
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        }, this.o.push(this.p), this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(a) {
          this.p.x = a.clientX - this.canvas.offsetLeft, this.p.y = a.clientY - this.canvas.offsetTop
        }.bind(this)), this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(a) {
          this.p.velocity = {
            x: (Math.random() - .5) * this.options.velocity,
            y: (Math.random() - .5) * this.options.velocity
          }, this.p = new c(this), this.p.velocity = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
          }, this.o.push(this.p)
        }.bind(this))), requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this))
      }, b.prototype.update = function() {
        this.g.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height), this.g.globalAlpha = 1;
        for (var a = 0; a < this.o.length; a++) {
          this.o[a].update(), this.o[a].h();
          for (var b = this.o.length - 1; b > a; b--) {
            var c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.o[a].x - this.o[b].x, 2) + Math.pow(this.o[a].y - this.o[b].y, 2));
            c > 120 || (this.g.beginPath(), this.g.strokeStyle = this.options.particleColor, this.g.globalAlpha = (120 - c) / 120, this.g.lineWidth = .7, this.g.moveTo(this.o[a].x, this.o[a].y), this.g.lineTo(this.o[b].x, this.o[b].y), this.g.stroke())
          }
        }
        0 !== this.options.velocity && requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this))
      }, b.prototype.setVelocity = function(a) {
        return "fast" === a ? 1 : "slow" === a ? .33 : "none" === a ? 0 : .66
      }, b.prototype.j = function(a) {
        return "high" === a ? 5e3 : "low" === a ? 2e4 : isNaN(parseInt(a, 10)) ? 1e4 : a
      }, b.prototype.l = function(a, b) {
        for (var c in b) a.style[c] = b[c]
      }, b
    });

    // Initialisation

    var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('particle-canvas');
    var options = {
      particleColor: '#888',
      interactive: true,
      speed: 'medium',
      density: 'high'
    };
    var particleCanvas = new ParticleNetwork(canvasDiv, options);
  </script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @A Haworth ok thanks i don't really know javascript what i need to change so that the canvas is transparent or leave this blue color ?

Comment: @A Haworth for leave this color   #1a252f because i have 3 files, style.css script.js and index.php when i copy past your code in file index.php i don't see the particules, and when i copy your code in my 3 files this don't change i dont see my pictures or when i click in navbar (in mobile version) it's not open the menu

Comment: Sorry, I am very confused by your comment. All I was suggesting that you do is alter the z-index of the canvas. Where exactly are you putting that?

Comment: @A Haworth check i have host check result
http://test11789456ttt.42web.io/?i=1# the canvas is above all the site but I would like it to be in the background. Because look when I put in mobile version we do not see the menu and the navbar

Comment: Plese use your browsers devtools inspect facility to see exactly what/where is putting the background on the various divs and what their z-indexs are. The scenario in your live site is slightly different from the snippet of code you provided.

Comment: @A Haworth
 in my computer do the same but ok